# Finding eigenvalues of $A=PDP^{-1}$ for $3\times3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the equation $A=PDP^{-1}$ for $3 \times 3$ matrices, where $P$ and $D$ are known and $D$ is a diagonal matrix, how can I use this information to find the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: $A$ and $D$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That was a no-brainer, right?!

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I edited your post to make the $\LaTeX$ work.  Remember to enclose your $\LaTeX$ in "\$" signs to make it render prooerly:  "\$ \alpha \$" yields $\alpha$!

Comment: they're similar boi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any two square $n \times n$ matrices $M$ and $N$ such that

$M = PNP^{-1}, \tag{1}$

the eigenvalues are the same.  For if

$N \vec v =\mu \vec v, \tag{2}$

with $\vec v \ne 0$, then

$M(P\vec v) = PNP^{-1}(P\vec v) = PN\vec v = P(\mu \vec v) = \mu P \vec v, \tag{3}$

showing that $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ with eigenvector $Pv \ne 0$.   Thus every eigenvalue of $N$ is also one of $M$;  reversing the roles of $M$ and $N$ so that

$N = QMQ^{-1} \tag{4}$

where

$Q = P^{-1} \tag{5}$

shows the eigenvalues of $M$ are shared by $N$.  Thus the eigenvalues of $M$ and $N$ are the same.  Now take $N = D$ and $M = A$.  Since $D$ is diagonal, the eigenvalues of $D$ are simply its diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the *characteristic polynomial* of a square matrix $M$ is the polynomial $\chi_M(t)=\det(t\cdot I-M)$. The eigenvalues of $M$ are the roots of $\chi_M(t)$.

Now, suppose that $A=PBP^{-1}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\chi_A(t)
&= \det(t\cdot I-A) \\
&= \det\left(t\cdot I-PBP^{-1}\right) \\
&= \det\left(t\cdot PP^{-1}-PBP^{-1}\right) \\
&= \det\left( P(t\cdot I-B)P^{-1}\right) \\
&= \det(P)\det(t\cdot I - B)\det\left(P^{-1}\right) \\
&= \det(P)\det\left(P^{-1}\right)\det(t\cdot I-B) \\
&= \det\left(PP^{-1}\right)\det(t\cdot I-B) \\
&= \det(I)\det(t\cdot I-B) \\
&= 1\det(t\cdot I-B) \\
&= \det(t\cdot I-B) \\
&= \chi_B(t)
\end{align*}
That is, $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial. Thus $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.